# Efficient Multiple Row and Columns Lookup Django

Tags: python, django

I need an efficient query that can enable lookup on multiple table rows and different columns. I have the below model:

```
class Vahala(models.Model):
    tourist = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    can_visit = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    can_move_out = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I need to confirm if Mr A who is a tourist can visit a location named 'bali' and can also move out of a location named 'cape_verde'.

I want to believe the naive approach would be

```
check_a = Vahala.objects.filter(name='bali', can_visit=True, tourist__email='mra@mail.com')

check_b = Vahala.objects.filter(name='cape_verde', can_move_out=True, 
tourist__email='mra@mail.com')
```

check_a and check_b must exists() before Mr A can complete the process.

I need an efficient approach. I don't want to keep hitting the database multiple times. Is it possible to confirm the conditions via a single DB hit or at most two if the conditions are much? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter from the Users side and chain filters to make successive joins on a related model:

```
queryset = User.objects.filter(
    email='mra@mail.com'
).filter(
    vahala_set__name='bali',
    vahala_set__can_visit=True
).filter(
    vahala_set__name='cape_verde',
    vahala_set__can_move_out=True
)
```

This will perform a join between User, Vahala and Vahala (twice, due to chained filter on the related model) and give you only users that match the given conditions.